# Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "." in SIKULI

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, sikuli-script

I was trying to run my code then add sikuli in my selenium project in order to click the allow in flash player settings.

[I need to click the allow in flash player settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyTR7.png)

```
Screen s = new Screen();
Pattern allowImg = new Pattern("allow.PNG");
s.click(allowImg);
s.click(allowImg);
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "."
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at org.sikuli.basics.Settings.<clinit>(Settings.java:123)
```

Comment: Are you sure this exception is caused by one of the lines in the code that you posted?

Comment: @EugeneS yes. and i'm not sure why.

That problem occurs when I was using maven. but when I try to manually add the dependency it works fine.